# How can I fit a model with 2 outputs thru one loss function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a model that has to return coordinates and then it has to return a confidence with it.  My loss function has to take into account the target coordinates and the target availability's.  Here is what my loss function looks like:

```py
def loss(targets, target_availabilities, preds, confidences):
    # my loss function goes here
    return loss
```

The functional API of TensorFlow shows how to pass 2 different outputs through separate loss functions (or the same loss function which return 2 loss values, one for each pair of `y_true` and `y_pred`).  How should I compile and fit my model so that it takes the targets, target_availabilities, predictions, and confidences through that single loss function?

Comment: I edited my answer there was a small mistake in the print statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a custom training loop to implement this. It allows for more flexibility. As long as you return one value, you can perform any type of computation in your loss function. Let's say that you want to do this:

```
transformed_output = (y_pred * confidence) - availability
```

You can implement this in a custom loss function (assuming that your neural net architecture returns these three values):

```
def compute_loss(model, x, y, training):
  out, avail, conf = model(inputs=x, training=training)
  transformed_output = tf.add(tf.multiply(out, conf), avail)
  loss = loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=transformed_output)
  return loss
```

This will return a value, and Tensorflow will try to minimize this value no matter what it is.

Here's a complete example. Let's say that this is 'availability`:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32, 
numpy=array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

And this is `confidences`:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.09586799, 0.03268242, 0.04225421, 0.4026084 , 0.5088273 ,
        0.38777208, 0.53815687, 0.41644037, 0.5709661 , 0.7587745 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Let's train a CNN to classify MNIST according to this special loss function.

```
import tensorflow as tf

(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

unsqueeze = lambda x, y: (tf.expand_dims(
    tf.divide(
        tf.cast(x, tf.float32), 255), -1),
                          tf.one_hot(y, depth=10))

train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtrain, ytrain)).\
    shuffle(64).\
    batch(64).\
    map(unsqueeze).\
    prefetch(1)

test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtest, ytest)).\
    shuffle(64).\
    batch(64).\
    map(unsqueeze).\
    prefetch(1)

class CNN(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                            strides=(1, 1),
                                            input_shape=(28, 28, 1))
        self.maxp1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                            strides=(1, 1))
        self.maxp2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
        self.flat1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.dens1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')
        self.drop1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(5e-1)
        self.dens3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.maxp1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxp2(x)
        x = self.flat1(x)
        x = self.dens1(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)
        x = self.dens3(x)
        availability = tf.cast(tf.random.uniform((len(x), 10), 0, 2,
                                                 dtype=tf.int32), tf.float32)
        confidences = tf.random.uniform((len(x), 10), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)
        return x, availability, confidences

model = CNN()

loss_object = tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)


def compute_loss(model, x, y, training):
  out, avail, conf = model(inputs=x, training=training)
  transformed_output = tf.add(tf.multiply(out, conf), avail)
  loss = loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=transformed_output)
  return loss


def get_grad(model, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = compute_loss(model, x, y, training=False)
    return loss, tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)


optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()

verbose = "Epoch {:2d} Loss: {:.3f} TLoss: {:.3f} Acc: {:.2%} TAcc: {:.2%}"


for epoch in range(1, 10 + 1):
    train_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
    train_acc = tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    test_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
    test_acc = tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()

    for x, y in train:
        loss_value, grads = get_grad(model, x, y)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
        train_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        train_acc.update_state(y, model(x, training=True))

    for x, y in test:
        loss_value, _ = get_grad(model, x, y)
        test_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        test_acc.update_state(y, model(x, training=False))


    print(verbose.format(epoch,
                         train_loss.result(),
                         test_loss.result(),
                         train_acc.result(),
                         test_acc.result()))
```

Comment: Do you have to create a separate class for the model or can we just use the `tf.keras.Model` wrapper?

Comment: You can do any of the two, as long as it returns the 3 outputs you mentioned.